# Would the Horcrux Cave Potion Have Killed Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

**Would the Horcrux cave potion have killed Dumbledore if:**

> Snape hadn't?

Kreacher survived the potion:

> ‘There was a b – basin full of potion on the island. The D – Dark Lord made Kreacher drink it ...’ [...] ‘Kreacher drank, and as he drank, he saw terrible things ... Kreacher’s insides burned ... Kreacher cried for Master Regulus to save him, he cried for his Mistress Black, but the Dark Lord only laughed ... he made Kreacher drink all the potion ...'
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 160 - Bloomsbury - chapter 10, *Kreacher's Tale*</sub>

Kreacher crawled to the lake for water and was dragged under by the Inferi who lived there, and Disapparated from the cave back to number 12 Grimmauld Place, per Regulus Black's instructions: ‘Master Regulus told Kreacher to come back,’ he said.

What I'm interested in knowing is whether Kreacher survived Voldemort's potion because he was a house-elf and house-elf magic is different than wizarding magic, or if he survived drinking the potion because while it was a devastatingly horrible potion to drink, it was not lethal -- not lethal to either house-elves *or* wizards.

**Therefore, I'm wondering if**

> **Snape had not killed Dumbledore after Dumbledore and Harry arrived back from the Horcrux cave**

**whether Dumbledore would have ultimately died from the Horcrux potion?**

An answer in the spirit of canon would be very welcome.

Comment: I think this is covered by Dumbledore's comments about how V wouldn't want to kill anyone who found the cave right away.  I always assumed he'd want to do the killing himself ie the potion *wouldn't* kill anyone who drank it.

Comment: Would you be willing to make it into an answer? I don't remember that bit about Voldemort, but it sounds interesting.

Comment: Dumbledore wasn't dying because of the potion. He was dying because of a cursed ring, if I remember correctly.

Comment: If so Kreacher wouldn't be alive, would he? Unless of course you consider that Dumbledore might have been too weak to get water or if he did he'd be too weak to fight off the inferi. But he had Harry there and there was enough time for him to recover enough to protect against the inferi. As vsz says the death would have been from something else namely a certain curse which Severus contained for a while. As for Kreacher he probably would have died (water, inferi) IF he HADN'T had the ability to return to his master (who had told him to return) and so in a sense the house elf magic DID save him.

Comment: @Pryftan - Kreacher and Dumbledore are not of the same species. What kills a House-Elf might not kill a human, and vice versa. So the question still stands.

Comment: @Slytherincess That's a fair suggestion although I'm not sure I buy it entirely. It's true that maybe some additional things would kill them which might not kill a human and vice versa (much like wizards/witches seem to survive physical accidents more than Muggles) but whether that potion would have any difference I would say depends largely on the fact Kreacher is a lot smaller. But given that he underestimated elves (etc.) you have another argument for your view. I suspect though that he would rather Dumbledore go down under rather (here literally) than dying of the potion itself.

Comment: J.K. Rowling has said that House-Elf magic is different than wizarding magic; conversely, I would suggest that this could mean House-Elves might react differently to wizarding magic. That Kreacher is smaller just might be an advantage -- we just don't know. Dumbledore notes that Voldemort would not get pleasure from killing someone quickly by the potion; he would prefer a longer, more drawn out, torturous death  on the part of the potion drinker. Whether death by drowning in a lake full of Inferi or by poison, Voldemort would want it to be terrible. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I accept your first point and agree with the second. Only responding now because I was in hospital until last night. But you make an interesting point actually: he uses AK when it's entirely painless. But I guess he did also torture people first a fair number of times and perhaps the terror of seeing him face to face was enough for his satisfaction.

Comment: Dumbledore was already dying from the cursed ring he was wearing. He would have died either way

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At the entrance to the Horcrux cave, Dumbledore says:

> "The idea ... is that your enemy must weaken him- or herself to enter."

Then, when they're discussing the potion in the basin:

> "But what if -- what if it kills you?"
>
> "Oh, I doubt that it would work like that," said Dumbledore easily.  "Lord Voldemort would not want to kill the person who reached this island."

and:

> "I'm sorry, Harry; I should have said, he would not want to *immediately* kill the person who reached this island," ... "He would want to keep them alive long enought to find out how they managed to penetrate so far through his defenses ..."

and:

> "Undoubtedly," he (Dumbledore) said finally, "this potion must act in a way that will prevent me from taking the Horcrux."

I can't recall anything offhand that addresses the issue of how Voldemort expected to be notified of someone getting into the cave, but I think the quotes above make it pretty clear that the potion was supposed to seriously incapacitate whoever drank it, but not kill them.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Ward's conclusion that the potion is not meant to kill the drinker especially given the evidence of the other 2 victims of the potion. However, I think Dumbledore is wrong on his assumption of *WHY* the potion will not kill him.

Lets investigate, first we have Dumbledore's comment.

> "Oh, I doubt that it would work like that," said Dumbledore easily. "Lord Voldemort would not want to kill the person who reached this island."

Showing that he doesn't believe the potion is meant to kill the drinker, here I think most of us agree that death from the potion is not the intention.

This is where I think Dumbledore's conclusions are slightly off.

> "I'm sorry, Harry; I should have said, he would not want to immediately kill the person who reached this island," ... "He would want to keep them alive long enough to find out how they managed to penetrate so far through his defenses ..."

While The potion does seem to incapacitate the drinker, it also has a side effect, making the drinker incredibly thirsty. The cup/potion itself does not appear to allow any liquid into the victims mouth, unless it's from the lake.

What do we know about this lake? Its filled with inferi.

What do these inferi do when you drink from the late? Immediately attack and kill you.

> “Kreacher needed water, he crawled to the island’s edge and he
> drank from the black lake ... and hands, dead hands, came out of
> the water and dragged Kreacher under the surface...”

We see Kreacher was attacked an dragged under the water by the inferi.

> And he drank — all the potion — and Kreacher swapped the lockets —
> and watched ... as Master Regulus ... was dragged beneath the
> water ... and ...”

Regulus, while not specifically stating he drank from the lake, he most likely did because of his thirst, and was dragged into the lake by the inferi.

> instinctively, the only way left to get water, because Voldemort had
> planned it so...
>
> He flung himself over to the edge of the rock and plunged the goblet
> into the lake, bringing it up full to the brim of icy water that did
> not vanish.
>
> “Sir — here!” Harry yelled, and lunging forward, he tipped the
> water clumsily over Dumbledore’s face.
>
> It was the best he could do, for the icy feeling on his arm not
> holding the cup was not the lingering chill of the water. A slimy
> white hand had gripped his wrist, and the creature to whom it belonged was pulling him, slowly, backward across the rock.

As Harry states, he knew instinctively what Voldemort had done, made it so you had to drink water from the lake, the water that activated the inferi, to attack and kill you. Which shows the intention of death from inferi, and not the potion, which would not keep the person who found the locket alive long enough for Voldemort to question them, as Dumbledore suspected.